# Git unstage lines where the only changes is white-space?

Tags: git, whitespace, indentation

I have a source code file that for some reason have ended up with mixed indentation (spaces and tabs used for indentation).

I have made quite a few changes and now I wish to commit those changes in git. Unfortunately I by accident instructed my editor to fix all indentation. So now it looks like I have modified a lot of lines, where the only change is changes to white-space.

My commit has to be reviewed by my colleagues in [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/), so having a lot of white-space-only changed lines show up as changes adds a lot of noise.

**How can I unstage all lines in a file, where the only change is to white-space (or indentation), such that my git commit only contains actually changed lines?**

(Or alternatively, how can I only stage the lines of a file where more than white-space is changed?)

Comment: It occurs to me that Gerrit ought to be able to show a diff with whitespace ignored (as `diff -w`).  If not, perhaps you should suggest it as a feature to them.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Absolutely, but gerrit aside, it would still be useful to know how to not commit lines where the only change is to white-space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 git diff -w --no-color [file names] | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

Basically it applies the patch which would be applied with add without whitespace changes. You will notice that after that there will still be unstaged changes, it's the whitespaces left, to checkout them run: `git checkout .`

Comment: I developed [a script](https://gist.github.com/atfornes/f4a917c6c0cf5b773824a6545ae2ef5e) to apply this solution to the commits of a branch when rebasing another branch.

Comment: This answer mostly worked for me.  4 of my 38 files failed with a "patch does not apply" warning.  I ended up stashing my changes (`git stash save`), re-applying them (`git stash apply`), reverting the four failed files, following the steps from this answer, checking out the four files from the stash `git checkout stash@{0} -- file1 file2 file3 file4`, and then manually fixing the whitespace for those four.  Still way better than fixing all 38 files manually.